Dataproc : unable to find environment properties by archive path
I submit a dataproc job as below:
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark \
gs://persopnal/test/file1.py \
--py-files gs://persopnal/test/file1.py,gs://persopnal/test/file2.py \
--jars $jar \
--archieves gs://persopnal/test/py37-p-env.zip$ImageEnv \
--properties spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_HOME=./ImageEnv/py37-p-env/bin/python \
--region $region \
--cluster $cluster \
--project $project \
-- \
-i 1
-p 1

but it throws an exception like this:

Can not run program "./ImageEnv/py37-p-env/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory

I unpack gs://persopnal/test/py37-p-env.zip and I can find ./ImageEnv/py37-p-env/bin/python
Is there any problem with this ZIP archive?
I want to know why this error occurs, and how to solve it, because there are too many files in py37-p-env.zip, I can't add them to --files parameter
